# First install of Qt 5 on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, build

I thought I'd learn something about making graphical programs and downloaded Qt5 with MinGW for Windows from the website. I've done the tutorial as here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/gettingstartedqt.html

However, upon building the project the following (likely n00bish thing) happens:

```
:-1: error: cannot find -lqtmaind
:-1: error: cannot find -lQt5Widgetsd
:-1: error: cannot find -lQt5Guid
:-1: error: cannot find -lQt5Cored
:-1: error: cannot find -llibEGLd
:-1: error: cannot find -llibGLESv2d
:-1: error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

From what I gather this is probably something to do with how my setup is - although I would have thought downloading with MinGW would have prevented any issue with not having something or something being put in the wrong place. I also have code blocks on my machine and have been compiling .exe's whilst learning C++ without any issue.

Comment: The linker cannot find the libraries it needs. Have you given it the correct paths?

Comment: From what I can tell, the stuff it needs is in C:\Qt\Qt5.0.5\mingw\lib.... it looks to me as if everything needed to use C++ is in here or in C:\Qt\Qt5.0.5\tools\MinGW\*everything in here* including g++. On my PC I already have a i686-w64-mingw32 where my RTools is and in my CodeBlocks directory... Perhaps I can uninstall this stuff and put MinGW in just one place and have them all point to it?

Comment: C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\bin is in my PATH

Comment: make sure that it is the first one in your path...  so instead of getting tacked on the end of your list of paths, move it to the front, so that it finds g++ in the Qt folder instead of in the codeblocks folder.

Comment: I needed to add C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\Tools\MinGW\bin to the beginning of my path.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\Tools\MinGW\bin to the beginning of the PATH.

Comment: I'm glad it worked! I should have been more confident in my comment above.  :)

Comment: I've been learning C++ for a while now but a lot of the standard text's I've used really only use the stuff that is already on the system in MinGW and is common like <iostream> or the string stuff when they talk about including extra stuff.

Comment: The standard library is available with almost any compiler.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11  MingW allows you to use gdb, though other compilers have other debuggers available.